# How to perform addition on javascript object methods created with constructor functions

Tags: javascript, methods

In the code below I created a constructor function. I would like to add the value called **total** of two objects (one is called **candy** and the other is called **computer**). They obviously won't add...they concatenate. However, when I perform multiplication it multiplies as expected. What do I need to do to perform addition to them ?

Code is below.For my example I use multiplication and I commented the troubled area.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<meta charset="UTF-8"> 
<title>checkoutTemplate</title>

<script>
function Item (item,price,tax,addedFee,total){
    this.item = item;
    this.price = price;
    this.tax = function () {
    if (typeof tax == 'undefined')
    {
        tax = price * .10;          
    } 
    else {
        tax = 0;
    }
    return tax;
    };

    this.addedFee = function () {
    if (typeof addedFee == 'undefined')
    {
        addedFee = price * .05;         
    } 
    else {
        addedFee = 0;
    }
    return addedFee;
    };


    this.total = function () {return this.price+ this.tax()+ this.addedFee()};


};



var computer = new Item("computer", 1000,"NA","NA");
var candy = new Item("candy", 0.50,"NA","NA");


document.write( "the total output value: " + candy.total() * computer.total() ); // Troubled area. I want to add candy.total and computer.total.Not multiply.
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `()` to let number plus perform first:

```
"the total output value: " + (candy.total() + computer.total())
```

Comment: I tried this before I posted. I guess it was a syntax error on my part. Thanks.